# R user-defined function saving graphics - error with dev.off()?

Tags: r, function, plot, save

I am trying to create a function that would do the plots of my PCA (prcomp object). These plots would be then saved in the directory set as one of the arguments of the function.

Whenever I do it separately it works. The graphics can be printed from the function (so there is no major issue in the code). The function does create a file in the right directory, with the right name BUT it is all blank...

Here is the code (a bit long..):

```
#arg1: the PCA object that we want to plot
#arg2: the list of sample names
#arg3: where to save the plots
#arg4: description of the treatment done

PlotPCA<- function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4){

  library(ggplot2)
  DFplot<-data.frame(arg1$x, Sple=arg2)
  arg2<-as.factor(arg2)
  DFplot.PoV <- arg1$sdev^2/sum(arg1$sdev^2)
  LoadMat1 <- arg1$rotation             # the matrix of variable loadings (i.e., a matrix whose columns contain the eigenvectors)
  ScoreMat1 <- predict(arg1)
  percentage<-paste( colnames(DFplot), "(", paste(as.character((round(DFplot.PoV, digits = 4))*100), "%", ")", sep="") )

  themePCA<-theme(panel.background = element_blank(),panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"),axis.ticks=element_line(colour="black"),plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"line"))


  setwd(arg3)
  png(file=paste0("PC1$2 on ",arg4,Sys.Date(),".png"),width=4000,height=3000,res =300)
  ggplot(DFplot,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,col=arg2, label=arg2))+
    labs(title=paste0("PC1$2 on",arg4,Sys.Date()),
         colour="Samples (same color =
         same composition)")+
    geom_text()+                     # Add labels
    themePCA+                       #for whit background
    xlab(percentage[1])+ ylab(percentage[2])+
    theme(legend.position="none")
  dev.off()

  setwd(arg3)
  png(file=paste0("PC2$3 on ", arg4, Sys.Date(), ".png"), width=4000,height=3000,res =300,antialias = c("default"))
  ggplot(DFplot,aes(x=PC3,y=PC4,col=arg2, label=arg2))+
    labs(title=paste0("PC2$3 on", arg4, Sys.Date()),
         colour="Samples (same color =
         same composition)")+
    #geom_point(size=0.5,alpha=0.5)+ #Size and alpha just for fun
    geom_text()+                     # Add labels
    #scale_color_manual(values=ColPB)+
    themePCA+                       #for whit background
    xlab(percentage[3])+ ylab(percentage[4])+
    theme(legend.position="none")
  dev.off()
}'
```

I have the impression in comes from dev.off() as I get

> null device 
>             1

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Running `setwd(arg3)` within a function environment is probably not a good idea...perhaps an argument `path_to_save` would be better

Comment: Print your ggplot object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your plot in a variable like `p <- ggplot(...) + ...` and then either print the variable `print(p)` or -much better- use the function `ggsave` which is the intended way to save plots created with ggplot2.